# Convert day format in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
DateFormat('E').format(DateTime.now())
```

How to convert the day format like M, T, W, T, F, etc instead of Mon, Tue, etc in flutter?

Comment: Just take the first letter :D

Comment: DateFormat('E').format(DateTime.now()).substring(0,1);

Answer (score 1):

While taking the first character will do the trick, you would need to do that in every call of the `format` method. To modify an existing `DateFormat` to be able to format days like that, you can create a custom class that extends `DateFormat` and overrides the `format` method like this:

```dart
class CustomDateFormat extends DateFormat {
  CustomDateFormat() : super.E();

  @override
  String format(DateTime date) {
    return super.format(date).characters.first;
  }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```dart
final dateFormat = CustomDateFormat();
final formattedDate = dateFormat.format(DateTime.now());
```